# html-webpack-plugin multiple entry points adding all scripts

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, multiple-entries

I'm building a project on an ejected react cli. The reason I ejected it is because there will be multiple pages being generated and some stand alone scripts that I wanted to make and have them take advantage of the ES6 and debugging tools provided by the boilerplate.

My problem is that while using the [technique](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/218#issuecomment-183066602) to build out multiple pages with  `html-webpack-plugin` builds out the generated HTML files with both scripts from each page.

So, lets have a look at the basic entry point

Here's my basic web pack config.

```
...
entry: {

      devServerClient : require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
      // Finally, this is your app's code:
      ...pages,

    },
...
```

As you can see, I'm using the same hot module reloading stuff that came with the boiler plate, but then I deviate to spread in values from the pages variable which is being required from another page:

```
const glob = require("glob");
const path = require("path");

const input_path = path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/apps/*/index.js");
const apps_directories = glob.sync(input_path);

let pages = {};

// Loop through them and append them to the pages object for processing.
apps_directories.map(function (app_directory) {
    const split_name = app_directory.split("/");
    pages[split_name[split_name.length - 2]] = app_directory;
});

module.exports = pages;
```

Thats how I generate multiple entries dynamically. This portion of the code works fine, but I thought I'd post it just in case something needs to happen here that I'm missing.

Next We have the actual plugin section. I take a similar approach in modularizing the code, so here's that portion in the config (root level of the web pack object):

```
...
plugins: [
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    ...HtmlWebpackPlugins,
    ...
]
...
```

Again, I spread them in, the script that generates these looks like so:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const pages = require("./multiplePaths");
const paths = require("./paths");

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;

let HtmlWebpackPlugins = [];

Object.keys(pages).map(function (fileName) {
    if (NODE_ENV === "development") {
        HtmlWebpackPlugins.push( new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
            filename: `${fileName}.html`,
        }));
        return;
    }

    HtmlWebpackPlugins.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: true,
        template: paths.appHtml,
        filename:  `${fileName}.html`,
        minify: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            removeRedundantAttributes: true,
            useShortDoctype: true,
            removeEmptyAttributes: true,
            removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
            keepClosingSlash: true,
            minifyJS: true,
            minifyCSS: true,
            minifyURLs: true,
        },
    }));
});

module.exports = HtmlWebpackPlugins;
```

This script here generates the multiple instances of the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` class per entry, and we also name the html file based on the folder the name of the folder the app resides in. This satisfies the [technique](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/218#issuecomment-183066602) in their issues section.

The problem then happens in the generated HTML page. Notice that the scripts for all the folders are injected in each app:

[image]

As you can see, each app's CSS and JS are added. This happens to both pages. I only want the relevant CSS and JS to each page.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to add only some of the chunks inside each page you need to specify which chunks exactly you want to have inside your html as scripts:

```
HtmlWebpackPlugins.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: true,
    template: paths.appHtml,
    filename:  `${fileName}.html`,
    chunks: [filename], // add any chunks you need here (for example, chunk with libraries
    ....
});
```

Comment: Wow, this fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this to create entries for HtmlWebpackPlugin based on webpack entries:

```
// Webpack entries
const entry = {
  "nameA": "./xy/nameA/main.js",
  "nameB": "./xy/nameB/main.js",
};

// Plugins
let plugins = [];

// HTML injection
Object.keys(entry).forEach((ent) => {
    const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      title: "Your Title",
      template: "./html/index.html",
      filename: `formats/${ent}/index.html`,
      chunks: [ent],
    });
    plugins.push(htmlPlugin);
});

// Insert more plugins
plugins = plugins.concat([
    ... your plugins
]);

// Return Config
return {
  // define entry point
  entry,

  // define output file
  output: {
      ...
  },

  ...

  // define Plugins
  plugins,
  
  ...
  
  };
```